# When did GAFE (Google Apps for Education) become G Suite?

Tags: google-workspace, google-workspace-for-business

When did GAFE (Google Apps for Education) become G Suite?

Comment: You are asking two questions here. The questions about tags on webapps.stackexchange.com should be directed to webapps.meta.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Why was this question downvoted and voted to close?  Can the question be improved by editing?

Comment: Yes, see my first comment. We like questions to be as specific as possible. If you have two questions, post two different questions. In this case, the other question (about tags) is best suited for webapps.META.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question doesn't show any search/research effort. Reference [ask].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Google Apps* was renamed *G Suite* [on September 26, 2016](https://cloud.googleblog.com/2016/09/all-together-now-introducing-G-Suite.html).

*G Suite for Education* was introduced [on October 4, 2016](https://blog.google/topics/education/introducing-g-suite-education/).

Comment: How do people pronounce G Suite for Education?  If they are in an education environment, do they just say "G Suite"?  Do they use an acronym, such as GSE (analogous to the old GAFE)?  Do they still say GAFE out of habit?  Do I need to ask a separate question?

Comment: @aparente001 That is really not a question for this site, which is about _using web applications_. Perhaps you should take the [tour](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour), see which questions are [on topic](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and browse around the site for a while to find out what questions are being asked here.

Comment: Well, take you for example.  You were knowledgeable enough about G Suite for Education to be able to answer my question; this suggests that perhaps you have conversed with others about it on occasion; if so, how do *you* refer to it?  I'm pretty sure I can ask this on ELU SE, but I'm also pretty sure no one there will know the answer....

Comment: I was about to post the self-same links. A simple web search for "google apps for education is now g suite" or similar would have found the same information.

Comment: @aparente001 The fact that some people on this site _might know something about a topic_ does not necessarily make that topic relevant for this site. I downvoted this question, because I feel it is off topic here. I _also_ answered it, in case the question is left open. Please see the [help/on-topic] - the guidelines for on topicness are actually quite specific.

Comment: Now I'm confused.  I thought you were saying the pronunciation question in my comment was off topic.  Earlier, I thought you said the question question was badly posed because it wasn't granular enough -- which I thought I resolved by removing the second question and posting it in Meta.

Comment: @aparente001 Yes, all of the above. The _tag improvement_ part is about _using this site_, so it belongs on Meta. The question _When did ... ?_ is not really about _using a web application_, so I think it is off topic here, and voted to close. _How do you pronounce ... ?_ is a new question posted as a comment, and _if_ it was posted as a question, would also not be about using a web application → off topic. **Please** see the [help] - remember, this is a Q&A site, **not a forum**.

Comment: I appreciated your guidance re the tag improvement part, and promptly posted on Meta. // Re the *when did* question -- I had not understood until now that you felt it was off topic.  I recently learned via a comment to my Meta question that there is a related Q&A at https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4072/85534.  But I think your answer here was direct, to the point and well documented and I personally would like to see it stay. // Re the comment -- I don't think questions should be judged by the comments associated with them; but do flag the question or the comment if appropriate.